# How can I get tesseract regular english language package for Alpine linux?

Tags: linux, docker, ocr, tesseract, alpine-linux

I am building a docker image based on alpine that has a dependency with tesseract for OCR. The tesseract [site](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/Data-Files-in-different-versions.html) list two flavors of English, eng (modern english) and enm (middle english). However, I am having issues getting the eng version installed on Alpine.

My Dockerfile has the following:

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jre-alpine as tesseract-master

RUN apk update && apk add tesseract-ocr
RUN apk update && apk add tesseract-ocr-data-eng
```

This fails to find the eng language package. During the build process, [repo](https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.17/community/aarch64/) is listed and it is clear that it does not have the eng package.

I am able to install the enm package, but I feel like there will be issues since it is for middle english.

Has anyone had success installing the eng package on Alpine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the content one of those packages for a language, for example the `tesseract-ocr-data-enm` one, you will quickly realise it contains only one file:

- */usr/share/tessdata/enm.traineddata*

<sup>*Source: https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?name=tesseract-ocr-data-enm&branch=v3.17&arch=aarch64*</sup>

Now, if you reverse engineer it, you can try to find which package does contains the file */usr/share/tessdata/eng.traineddata*, and it is, with no big surprise, the default package: `tesseract-ocr`.

<sup>*Source: https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?file=eng.traineddata&branch=v3.17&arch=aarch64*</sup>

So, your *Dockerfile* should simply be:

```bash
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jre-alpine as tesseract-master

RUN apk add --no-cache \
      tesseract-ocr
```